# How can I create a PDF in Javascript, then use that data to recreate it in ColdFusion?

Tags: javascript, pdf, amazon-s3, coldfusion

Forgive the lack of code but I'm working in a production environment and it's a lot. I can provide more specific examples if needed but I will explain the basic situation here.

I'm using a library called PdfMake (which is excellent btw, great for making pdf's in JS if you need that) to make a dynamic PDF on the fly.

Now I need to get the PDF into an S3 bucket, but our stack currently relies on ColdFusion. Luckily, PdfMake has a handy method to convert the pdf data to Base64 and ColdFusion has a handy function to convert Base64 to binary.

So I sent the base64 to my server, convert it to binary, make a new coldfusion pdf and read it like this (fileData is a base64 encoded string)

```
public function upload_pdf(string fileName, any fileData){
    var myPdf = new pdf();
    var binary = ToBinary(arguments.fileData);
    myPdf.read( source=binary, name="fileSource");
}
```

For some reason this action is failing. I usually get an error that says "The Document has no catalog of type dictionary", which is very cryptic and brings up no helpful results when I search it. Sometimes, without changing anything, I get an error that reads "the rebuild document still has no trailer". From googling it seems trailers are something specific to do with PDFs.

Intuitively I would think that this would work, since base64 and binary are versatile types of encoding. However I'm at a loss as to how to even begin to fix or diagnose this. I will probably begin looking for another solution altogether but I am curious to learn more about what is happening here so if anyone has any ideas I am down for some discussion.

FOR ANY CURIOUS READERS I HAVE SOLVED THIS PROBLEM, HERE IS THE WORKING CODE:

```
public function upload_pdf(string fileName, string fileData){
    var myPdf = new pdf();
    var binary = decodeBinary(Replace(arguments.fileData, " ", "+", "ALL"));
    myPdf.setSource(binary);
}
```

Comment: Troubleshoot the problem in a development environment.

Comment: Obviously I am, I just meant I am working with production code so the quantity is great and it's difficult to share

Comment: Can you share the bit of ColdFusion code where you are converting the string back to binary and re-creating the PDF?

Comment: I have that in the code snippet above, what else are you looking for? fileData is the base64 string,ToBinary() converts it to binary, myPdf.read() turns that binary into a pdf (or thats what I want it to do)

Comment: Oops, sorry. I totally read passed that. Instead of using `toBinary(arguments.fileData)` try using `binaryDecode(arguments.fileData,'base64')`

Comment: That was a good thought, I tried it but I am getting the same errors. It's frustrating because the error is consistently different (either "there was an error during the read operation", "the document has no catalog of type dictionary", or "the rebuilt document still has no trailer") and I can't seem to pin down what is changing under the hood.

Comment: I would stick with the `binaryDecode()` function as `toBinary()` is deprecated. Not sure why it is not working for you. I have similar code working. Is it failing on the `myPdf.read()` line? How are you passing the data to your ColdFusion server?

Comment: I think I've got a better lock on it now, as I passed the data to my backend with an ajax call it was being sanitized for some odd reason. I desanitized it and used binaryDecode and instead of using pdf.read() I switched to pdf.setSource() and those errors are gone. Problem is, I am now having trouble uploading the file. I think I fundamentally misunderstood how the file upload works, because I can't pass my PDF in as an argument and I get the error "complex data types cannot be converted to simple values"